# XCode 4. Keyboard doesn't hide on iPad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, keyboard

I have a problem with my iPad app.

I perform authorization in social networks (facebook, twitter etc.) to post information from app. Several webviews change each other (login, content of post, captcha). They have text fields and I have to show keyboard. After posting I return to some start view with posted information.

It works good, but after posting first news something goes wrong. When I post news one more time, after return keyboard is still on the screen.

I saw here some questions familiar to this, but they wasn't useful.

I tried to make resignFirstRersponder to all webViews, textFields and textViews. Also i\I tried to implement method   disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal  but it doesn't help me.

I don't know where search for problem...

So questions are: why could this happened? How can I solve this? fnd How can I get some information about keyboard? (is it visible, what object has focus etc., anything that could be useful to solve problem)

And one more thing. I have similar app for iPhone and it seems to work correct.

Comment: Please post your code to get us clear idea of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[searchBar performSelector:@selector(resignFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

Make sure to replace searchBar with the object that is the actual First responder in your case

Answer (score 0):

Problem is fixed, finally. The reason was the way I had changed visible view. I set a new value to view property of ViewController. And as previous view contains text field with focus on it, focus wasn't lost before changing view (and keyboard was still on the screen), but I had lost handler to previous view.
Solution is: resignFirstResponder to all (or current) inputs BEFORE changing view.

Hope, it's clear. Thanks for your help!